# 1NF from table with multiple columns with differing number of repeating groups

Tags: sql

I want to normalize a table to 1NF but the problem is that what I learned online was doing 1NF when only one of the columns has a repeating group. I have a problem where 3 columns have repeating groups and want to do 1NF on them. Each repeating group in a column differs in size. So it beats me on how to do it. For example, if I have a table like this:

| name | courses | hobbies | fav_colors |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Michael | biology, chemistry | soccer, baseball, tennis | blue, yellow, red, green |
| Daniel | psychology | table tennis, basketball | yellow, red, orange, pink |

This is an illustrative example of what I have in the table. You can see that courses, hobbies, and fav_colors have repeating groups. How do I do 1NF on them with SQl? If anyone can show me with code (sql), I will be delighted because I am actually stumped and confused.
Thanks

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Answer (score 1):

You have a relationship many-to-many, in these cases you need to add an auxiliar table (called a join table) to do the relation, for example for the courses:

| ID_student | name | courses |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Michael | biology, chemistry |
| 2 | Daniel | psychology |

It can be transfor in:
| ID_student | name |
| :-------- | :-------------- |
| 1 | Michael |
| 2 | Daniel |

| ID_course | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | biology |
| 2 | chemistry |
| 3 | psychology |

Join table:

| ID_student | ID_course |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |

Comment: Now I get it. I need three tables all related to the student table